# loop plotting for columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, plot

I have a data frame with 12 columns, and I am trying to make some plots. I can't understand why this is not working:

```
for (i in 1:11) plot(red_wine_data[i],red_wine_data$quality, type="p")
```

(quality is the 12th column name)
this gives the following error:

```
Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method
```

I know there are other ways to do this, but why this is not working?

Comment: have you tried `for (i in 1:11) plot(red_wine_data[,i],red_wine_data$quality, type="p")` ? notice the `,` before `i`.

Comment: Because `red_wine_data[i]` returns a 1 column data.frame, not a vector. Use `[, i]` or `[[i]]`.